# 正規表現の作り方

Tags: 正規表現

以下の条件の正規表現を作成したいです。

1はじめと終わりはひらがな
2文字列中には空白1つまたは｢ぁ｣から｢ん｣。
3空白は0〜1つ続いていい
4文字列中に空白は任意の数現れてもよい

例

```
やまだたろう=>OK
やまだ たろう=>OK
やま だ たろう=>OK
や ま だ た ろ う=>OK
山田たろう=>NG      //漢字
山田 たろう=>NG     //漢字、空白
ヤマダ たろう=>NG   //カタカナ
Yamada Tarou=>NG  //英語
 やまだ たろう=>NG  //スペースではじまる
やまだ  たろう=>NG  //スペース2つ
```

以上を踏まえて下記の正規表現を作成しましたが、空白が2連続以上でもマッチしてしまいます。どこを直せばいいのかご教授いただけないでしょうか。

作成した正規表現

```
^[ぁ-ん][ぁ-ん]*|\s?[ぁ-ん]+$
```

Comment: `^[ぁ-ん](\s?[ぁ-ん])*$` ではどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

まずグループ化されない `|` は

```
  ^[ぁ-ん][ぁ-ん]*
|
  \s?[ぁ-ん]+$
```

と全体を分解しますからほとんど意図しないものになっています。「1. はじめと終わりはひらがな」なので

```
^[ぁ-ん]
  (
    [ぁ-ん]*
  |
    \s?
  )
[ぁ-ん]$
```

が求めるものに近いです。これでも`[ぁ-ん]*`と`\s?`のどちらかが出現してもよいという意味ですので、「空白が2連続以上」を認めています。発想を少しひねって

> 2. 文字列中には空白1つまたは｢ぁ｣から｢ん｣。
> 3. 空白は0〜1つ続いていい

を

2. 文字列中には空白1つまたは｢ぁ｣から｢ん｣。
3. 空白は｢ぁ｣から｢ん｣の直後に0～1つ

と捉えることができます。これを表す正規表現は

```
^[ぁ-ん]
  (
    [ぁ-ん]
    \s?
  )*
[ぁ-ん]$
```

ただしこのままでは2文字目が空白となれませんので、最終的に

```
^([ぁ-ん]\s?)+[ぁ-ん]$
```

となるでしょうか。